# No puedo iniciar sesion en mi sitio en drupal, con hybridauth

Tags: facebook

Mi problema es que al  intentar registrarme o login con **hybrid** auto la página queda cargando, y no termina, hasta que agota el tiempo de ejecución.

Estoy varado en eso ya he revisado todo, pero no tengo ningún resultado.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, por favor añade código para que podamos intentar reproducir el problema. Lee [ask] y proporciona un [mcve].

Comment: Falta mucha información en la pregunta: versión de Drupal, el módulo exacto que usas (hay varios de hybridauth) y su configuración, si has probado hacer login con otros servicios (en la captura se ve facebook)... No sé, toda la info que puedas proporcionar

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema, tenía el inicio de sesión de redes sociales con hibridauth en un proyecto de prueba y funcionaba correctamente, pero al momento de implementarlo en mi proyecto quedaba cargando, encontré que el problema era al momento de agregar boostrap-select con su .css y su .js, ahora mi problema es que no sé porqué ocurre este error.

Codigo de boostrap select (.js):

```
document.getElementById("btncomprarB").disabled = true;


$('.selectpicker').on('changed.bs.select', function (e) {

 if ($(".selectpicker").val()==null) {
document.getElementById("btncomprarB").disabled = true;
 }else {
document.getElementById("btncomprarB").disabled = false;
 }

});
```

cdn de boostrap-select:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```